# RXJava Scheduler and async callback api

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, rx-java

In our projet we use RXJava with CXF async (2 Rest services + 1 Soap service) and Mongodb async driver.

```
        public Observable<MyReturn> itineraries(MyQuery query) {

            return Observable.create((Observable.OnSubscribe<MyReturn>) subscriber -> {
                WebClient webclient = WebClient.fromClient(clientPrototype(), true);

                String myQuery = "" ;

                webclient.path("myPath",....);

                webclient.get(new InvocationCallback<MyClass>() {

                    @Override
                    public void completed(MyClass response) {
                        MyReturn myReturn = buildResponse(response);

                        subscriber.onNext(myReturn);
                        subscriber.onCompleted();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failed(Throwable throwable) {
                        subscriber.onError(new MyError(throwable));
                    }
                });

            });
```

I've a chained observables, and my problem is that my code is executed by the CXF Thread pool (i use a custom thread pool), and all other chained observables are executed in the same callaback CXF thread. So my processing go from callback thread to the next callback thread.

I tried "observerOn" giving my own thread pool, but it doesn't work, the code is executed in the callback thread.

For CXF, i can pass my own pool, so it's a design trouble. But with mongodb, i can't pass my thread pool (i didn't find a way to pass it), i've a random security permission problem even when i allow all operations with security manager activated.

Thank you.

Comment: How did you apply `observeOn`? The subscriber in itineraries(...).observeOn(Schedulers.computation()).subscribe(...) should receive the value on the computation thread.

Comment: @akanokd  thank you for your answer.
itineraries().flatMap(...).map(...)..(RX Observables operators chains)..observeOn(Schedulers.from(myPool)).subscribe(). There is no problem on the receive thread, i receive the flow in the correct thread. But the intermediate computing (between the call to CXF or Mongo and the final subscribe) is executed in the CXF or Mongodb thread.

Comment: Then put the `observeOn` just after the itineraries() call.

Comment: Thank you, It works when i add the observeOn on the Observable returned by itineraries.  So, the observeOn is not applied on all the observable chain ? i must put it on every observable where i want an other Scheduler ?

Comment: `observeOn` affects operators that come after it in the chain. If you want to observe things on other threads at different points of a pipeline, you have to apply `observeOn` at those points.

Comment: Thank you, so if i have 3 chained observables : a->b->c, and a, c execute async call where the callback executes in different thread. If i put the observeOn a, c will be executed in  the same scheduler as a ? Or i should add an other observeOn after c ?

Comment: It depends on how you chained those observables. Since any async boundary can have the execution jump to any thread, you should apply `observeOn` at critical points to make sure operators run on the desired thread.

Comment: Thank you, i try some tests, and i post a detailed response.